# Problemas com Jquery para pegar valor do input Text

Tags: html, jquery

nao estou conseguindo pegar o valor do input text, da o erro de indefinido... alguem saberia me responder pq esta assim???

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#btnPesquisar').click(function () {

                var x = $("#txtMatriculaPesquisar");
                alert(x.val());
               

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    url: 'Aluno.aspx/BuscaAluno',
                    data: "{'matircula':'" + matricula + "'}",
                    async: true,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (result) {
                        if (result != null) {
                            $.each(result.d, function (key, value) {
                                $('#txtNome').value = value.Nome;
                                $('#txtMatricula').value = value.Matricula;
                                $('#txtCpf').value = value.Cpf;
                                $('#txtNascimento').value = value.Data;

                            }); 
                        
                        }
                        
               
                    },
               });
            });
        });
```

```html
<div class="row">
            <div class="input-group col-md-6 col-md-offset-1">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Digite a Matricula" id="txtMatriculaPesquisar" value="" runat="server"/>
              <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="btnPesquisar">Pesquisar</button>
              </span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: como amigo, nao entendi??  ali é so um campo data de aniversario..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que você está armazenando a matrícula na variável `x` e depois passando a variável `matricula` para requisição. Como essa variável não existe, o *javascript* irá utilizar o valor de `Undefined`

Um outro erro é que, quando você captura um elemento com `jQuery` *(no `callback onSuccess`, por exemplo)*, ele te retorna um objeto. Como nesse objeto não existe a propriedade `value`, o código acaba de retornando um valor indefinido ou quando você tenta definir um novo valor, ele não funciona.

Quando você quiser capturar ou informar o valor a um objeto do `jQuery`, utilize:

```
$('#txtNome').val(); // Para capturar
$('#txtNome').val("novo-valor"); // Para definir
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#btnPesquisar').click(function () {

                let matricula = $("#txtMatriculaPesquisar");
                alert(matricula.val());
               

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    url: 'Aluno.aspx/BuscaAluno',
                    data: "{'matircula':'" + matricula + "'}",
                    async: true,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (result) {
                        if (result != null) {
                            $.each(result.d, function (key, value) {
                                $('#txtNome').val(value.Nome);
                                $('#txtMatricula').val(value.Matricula);
                                $('#txtCpf').val(value.Cpf);
                                $('#txtNascimento').val(value.Data);

                            }); 
                        
                        }
                        
               
                    },
               });
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
            <div class="input-group col-md-6 col-md-offset-1">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Digite a Matricula" id="txtMatriculaPesquisar" value="" runat="server"/>
              <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="btnPesquisar">Pesquisar</button>
              </span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: obg amigo , vou tentar aqui pra ver se da certo... nao entendo bem o funcionamento do jquery..  obg mesmo

Comment: achei o erro amigo, to usando ele no aspnet, e como tinha definido ele como runat = server, ele nao deixava eu recuperar no jquery

Comment: Elanio, realmente obtive o erro, como vc disse, no callback do onsuccess, so que estou procurando uma explicacao pra isso na internet, e nao consegui achar nada,,  vc poderia me explicar pq estou tendo esse erro, e como corrigilo, por favor??
obg: pequei essa funcao pronta na internet, mudei o q precisa e to usando, nao sei o q o for each  ta pegando no inicio dele nao

Comment: @CleitondeSousa fica difícil sem saber qual o `JSON` você está recebendo. O código que postei irá funcionar com um `Json Array`, mas caso você esteja recebendo um `Json Object`, você terá que remover o `$.each`